# Day of Week occurrences counter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that tracks when someone worked by tracking when they started working and when they finished working. I had some code that counted the number of Sundays that occurred in a table over a given date range.

This was my original code:

```
select empnum,
       count(distinct dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, starttime), 0)) as NumberOfSundays
from table
where (datename(dw, starttime) = 'Sunday') 
group by empnum
```

Now I need to also include occurrences when someone started on a Saturday but finished on a Sunday. However when I include an or statement to include these extra shifts, they count extra. That is, if someone works on Saturday and crosses into Sunday and then works again on Sunday I get a count of 2, when I only need a count of 1.

Here is my code, what do I need to change so that the Saturday or Sunday shifts only count as 1:

```
select empnum,
       count(distinct dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, starttime), 0)) as NumberOfSundays
from table
where (datename(dw, starttime) = 'Sunday' 
or (datename(dw, starttime) = 'Saturday' and datename(dw, endtime) = 'Sunday')) 
group by empnum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
SELECT empnum,
count(DISTINCT dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, starttime), 0)) AS NumberOfSundays
FROM TABLE
WHERE (
        datename(dw, starttime) = 'Sunday'
        OR (
            datename(dw, starttime) = 'Saturday'
            AND datename(dw, endtime) = 'Sunday'
            AND empnum NOT IN (
                SELECT empnum
                FROM TABLE
                WHERE datename(dw, starttime) = 'Sunday'
                )
            )
        )
GROUP BY empnum
```